# How to get os.system() output as a string and not a set of characters?

Tags: python, linux, shell, popen, os.system

I'm trying to get output from `os.system` using the following code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([some_directory], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
ls = p.communicate()[0]
```

when I print the output I get:

```
> print (ls)
```

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

The output somehow displays as two separate strings, However, when I try to print out the strings of filenames using a for loop i get
a list of characters instead:

```
>> for i in range(len(ls)):
>        print i, ls[i]
```

Output:

```
0 f
1 i
2 l
3 e
4 1
5 .
6 t
7 x
8 t
9 f
10 i
11 l
12 e
13 2
14 .
15 t
16 x
17 t
```

I need help ensuring the `os.system()` output returns as strings and
not a set of characters.

Answer (score 1):

`p.communicate` returns a *string*. It may look like a list of filenames, but it is just a string.  You can convert it to a list of filenames by splitting on the newline character:

```
s = p.communicate()[0]
for line in s.split("\n"):
    print "line:", line
```

Are you aware that there are built-in functions to get a list of files in a directory?

Comment: Hi Bryan. Thanx alot. That solves my problem. I am aware of the other built in functions. I'm working on updating files from a server and need to be able to check any new file updates. Thought about the new line split but wasn't sure it would work as I'm still very new to python ssh.

Answer (score 0):

`for i in range(len(...)):` is usually a code smell in Python. If you want to iterate over the numbered elements of a collection to canonical method is `for i, element in enumerate(...):`.

The code you quote clearly isn't the code you ran, since when you print `ls` you see two lines separated by a newline, but when you iterate over the characters of the string the newline doesn't appear.

The bottom line is that you *are* getting a string back from `communicate()[0]`, but you are then iterating over it, giving you the individual characters. I suspect what you would like to do is use the `.splt()` or `.splitlines()` method on `ls` to get the individual file names, but you are trying to run before you can walk. Forst of all, get a clear handle on what the `communicate` method is returning to you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, in Python 3.6, p.communicate returns *bytes* object:

```
In [16]: type(ls)
Out[16]: bytes
```

Following seems to work better:

```
In [22]: p = subprocess.Popen([some_directory], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
In [23]: ls = p.communicate()[0].split()

In [25]: for i in range(len(ls)):
    ...:     print(i, ls[i])
    ...: 
0 b'file1.txt'
1 b'file2.txt'
```

But I would rather use `os.listdir()` instead of `subprocess`:

```
import os
for line in os.listdir():
  print line
```